# Builders that differ by only one (of two) type parameters

Tags: scala

```
object Thing {
  def apply[T](s: String, f: T => Option[Boolean]) = ThingBuilder(s, f)
  def apply[T](s: String, f: T => Option[Long]) = ThingBuilder(s, f)
}

sealed trait Thing[T, U] {
  def name: String
  def get(t: T): Option[U]
}

trait BooleanThing[T] extends Thing[T, Boolean]
trait LongThing[T] extends Thing[T, Long]

object ThingBuilder {
  def apply[T](s: String, f: T => Option[Boolean]) = new BooleanThing[T] {
    override final val name: String = s
    override final def get(t: T): Option[Boolean] = f(t)
   }

  def apply[T](s: String, f: T => Option[Long]) = new LongThing[T] {
    override final val name: String = s
    override final def get(t: T): Option[Long] = f(t)
  }
}
```

As you can see, there's only one difference b/w `BooleanThing[T]` and `LongThing[T]` (the type `U`). The builder apply methods are basically copy/paste and switch out the type `U`. What's a better way to do this, to avoid the copy/paste nature of this?

(BTW, please do not suggest that I change a trait to a class, I need them to be traits like this.)

Answer (score 0):

I am inclined to believe you might need your instances of `Thing[T]` to be explicitly defined as `BooleanThing[T]` or `LongThing[T]` based on your requirement.

Otherwise, if all you need to manipulate is a `Thing[T]`, hiding away the concrete type of the second parameter type, then you could just add another parameter type in the `apply` methods:

```
object Thing {
    def apply[S, T](s: String, f: T => Option[S]) = ThingBuilder(s, f)
}

...

object ThingBuilder {
   def apply[S, T](s: String, f: T => Option[S]) = new Thing[T, S] {
       override final val name: String = s
       override final def get(t: T): Option[S] = f(t)
   }
}
```

The following compiled with Scala 2.12:

```
val a1: Thing[Int, Boolean] = Thing("Hello, Boolean", (x: Int) =>  Some(true))
val a2: Thing[_, Boolean] = a1

val b1: Thing[String, String] = Thing("Hello, String", Some(_: String))
val b2: Thing[_, String] = b1
```

The drawback of this is that we loses the specialization of the traits `BooleanThing` and `LongThing`.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I need the return type to be `BooleanThing` or `LongThing`, not just a generic `Thing`